# Google Sheets chart - dynamic min max Y axis from data

Tags: google-sheets, dynamic, charts

I have created a line chart in Google Sheets using data pulled from an API. The data changes every hour, so the min and max values of the data to chart also changes.

I would like to know if there is a script that can lookup up min and max from a column of data and use those values to dynamically set min/max for the Y axis.

Currently the only way I can see to change Y axis min max is manually in the chart editor, but the inputs only accept numbers, not formulas, so the min max is rigid.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Only applies to first y axis
// Only applies to charts on active spreadsheet
// Allows for multiple series
// Takes approx 3 seconds per 10 charts to run
// Change Sheet1 for your sheet name

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1')

var config = {
  // y-axis max is this factor higher than your chart's max value
  // For example if your max value is 100 and scaleUpBuffer is 0.1, 
  //   the y-axis max value will be set to 100 * (1 + 0.1) = 110
  scaleUpBuffer: 0.0001,

  // y-axis min is this factor lower than your chart's min value
  scaleDownBuffer: 0.0001,
  
  // If / when google fix goes through,
  //   set this to true and run fixCharts() to get default scaling back
  //   This sets min and max y axis values to null (the default)
  restoreDefault: false,
}


function fixCharts() {
  var minMaxY1;

  sheet.getCharts().forEach(function (chart) {

    minMaxY1 = config.restoreDefault ? [null, null] : getChartMinMaxY(chart, config);

    updatedChart = chart
      .modify()
      .setOption('vAxes', {0: {viewWindow: {min: minMaxY1[0], max: minMaxY1[1]}}})
      .build();
  
    sheet.updateChart(updatedChart);
  })
}

function getChartMinMaxY(chart, config) {
  var chartRangeArray,
      y1 = [];

  chart.getRanges().forEach(function(chartRange) {

    chartRangeArray = chartRange.getValues();

    chartRangeArray.forEach(function(row) {

      for (var i=1;i<row.length;i++) {
        // loops all series, assumes all on 1st y axis
        
        if (typeof row[i] == 'number') {
          // ignores blanks, headers, junk strings etc.
          y1.push(row[i]);
        }

      }
    });

  });

  return [
    Math.min.apply(null, y1) * (1 - config.scaleDownBuffer),
    Math.max.apply(null, y1) * (1 + config.scaleUpBuffer)
  ];
}
```